# C# Como quitar un namespace de un nodo

Tags: c#, xml

Hola me gustaria saber si existe una forma de eliminar un namespace de un nodo de un xml.

El namespace que tengo que eliminar es  **xmlns:cce11="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11"**, es el que aparece en el nodo **cce11:ComercioExterior**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante
    xmlns:pago10="http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos"
    xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital"
    xmlns:cce11="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/Pagos/Pagos10.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/ComercioExterior11/ComercioExterior11.xsd" Version="3.3" Serie="JB" Folio="260" Fecha="2020-10-13T14:40:37" FormaPago="03" SubTotal="4.50" Moneda="USD" TipoCambio="22.20" Total="4.50" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PPD" LugarExpedicion="45610"
    xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" NoCertificado="30001000000300023708" Certificado="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" Sello="OFQnjVFFP8CEapGb1OKsUFZMr1mozxAxs19n6Ay5TWiTlHuRQZyv9mwtDNctPxf7IsJ5yjv8lc1T7V2HrKiLytJFt9nHnTI34Hd6Y24bOI3FxR/+uYPdhYP28EWk3q8uJp9UA9pD3K7KnMUBJKa3BrfCjnv4Ev9xdq6Y40Pcq92lVIByMFyT6S+0iLoztcp2pRQFf7GWKPDmg1BQENJ781vkou7nbkIUJCiKhQs8BHXjMqw/7GCYoeoG0N+9Hv02Mzx7YaPOo+27XIg76cROoa6SnG604Wfcm2edzWr0QiAAfNe0w0tGQ2DiBAXSxk2FejB7lE9SMAPa0cS+p4GbTA==">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="AAA010101AAA" Nombre="Moldeos Especializados SA de CV" RegimenFiscal="601" />
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XEXX010101000" Nombre="INDUSTRIAS GANE, S.A. DE C.V." ResidenciaFiscal="USA" NumRegIdTrib="1150284000" UsoCFDI="G01" />
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="24122004" NoIdentificacion="AA" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="H87" Descripcion="AA" ValorUnitario="4.50369" Importe="4.5000">
            <cfdi:Impuestos>
                <cfdi:Traslados>
                    <cfdi:Traslado Base="4.5000" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0" Importe="0.00" />
                </cfdi:Traslados>
            </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="0.00">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0" Importe="0.00" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <cce11:ComercioExterior xmlns:cce11="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11" Version="1.1" MotivoTraslado="01" TipoOperacion="2" ClaveDePedimento="A1 " CertificadoOrigen="1" NumCertificadoOrigen="1234567890'09854334567890'09876543456789" Incoterm="CFR" Subdivision="0" TipoCambioUSD="22.20" TotalUSD="4.50">
            <cce11:Emisor>
                <cce11:Domicilio Calle="calle" NumeroExterior="154" NumeroInterior="281" Colonia="5331" Localidad="24" Municipio="002" Estado="JAL" Pais="MEX" CodigoPostal="45610" />
            </cce11:Emisor>
            <cce11:Receptor>
                <cce11:Domicilio Calle="North, Highway 177" NumeroExterior="14311" Colonia="Shawnee" Localidad="dsa" Municipio="Shawnee" Estado="OK" Pais="USA" CodigoPostal="74804" />
            </cce11:Receptor>
            <cce11:Mercancias>
                <cce11:Mercancia NoIdentificacion="AA" FraccionArancelaria="01012901" CantidadAduana="1" UnidadAduana="04" ValorUnitarioAduana="0.20" ValorDolares="4.50">
                    <cce11:DescripcionesEspecificas Marca="P1" />
                </cce11:Mercancia>
            </cce11:Mercancias>
        </cce11:ComercioExterior>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

He pensado en convertir el XmlDocument a string y quitar la segunda vez que aparezca  xmlns:cce11="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11" pero no se si se tiene otra forma más "facil" de hacerlo.

Comment: convierta el xml en un objeto

Comment: A mi me funciono hacer eso que comentas, lo pase a una variable string y de ahí reemplace el Namespace, segun lei no se pueden modificar los namespace de los xml